# How to replace all the special character who follows another character

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, typescript

I have a long string containing some special characters. I need to check those special characters who do not follow space and replace it with a special character and space.

Example
Input

```
var a = '<span>< hello < test<zero</span>';
```

Output

```
var a = '<span>< hello < test< zero</span>';
```

Here you can see the last `<` replaced with `<`  as it follows z which is not space. Keep this in mind in the HTML the special characters are coming in entities like

```
&lt;
```

> Regex solution will be great.

Comment: Can you add the code that you tried?

Comment: I followed a basic while loop finding the character and finding the position then adding +1 to the position and checked, that is working but I need a solution in regex.

Comment: You could use `<(?! )` and replace with the full match and space `$& ` https://regex101.com/r/o2fb8u/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird you are awesome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let a = '< hello < test<zero';

const pattern = /<(?!\s)/g;

let b = a.replace(pattern, "< ");

console.log(b)
```

Description of the pattern:

> a " < " character that is not followed by a white-space

Answer (score 0):

```
a.replace(/<([^\s]{1})/g, '< $1')
```

Comment: Thanks,  It only works for the first case, if I have many situations like this in the string it does not work

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it